# Unexpected problems concatenating strings

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm trying to concatenate strings using +, but there is some weird stuff going on. Here is my "Grade" class I have for a class project:

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Grade {
    private:
        string className;
        string student;
        string letter;

    public:
        Grade(string c, string s, string l) : className(c), student(s), letter(l) {}

        string getLetterGrade() const { return letter; }
        string getClassName() const { return className; }
        string getStudent() const { return student; }
        void setLetterGrade(string l) { letter = l; return;}
        void setClassName(string c) { className = c; return;}
        void setStudnet(string s) { student = s; return;}

        string toString() const { string output = "hello"+student; return output; }
};
```

Obviously, the toString() method isn't currently what I want it to be.
If I run the toString() as above, I get "hello529173860" out, as expected. However, if I change the line to:

```
string toString() const { string output = student+"hello"; return output; }
```

then the output is "hello3860". This isn't just putting the hello string on the front, but its replacing characters from the student string in the process... somehow?

Furthermore, if I try to use:

```
string toString() const { string output = "hello"+" world"; return output; }
```

I get an error:

```
Grade.h: In member function ‘std::string Grade::toString() const’:
Grade.h:29:53: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [6]’ and ‘const char [7]’ to binary ‘operator+’
   string toString() const { string output = "hello"+" world"; return output; }
                                                     ^
```

I'm really at a loss for what it going on here... especially since I have done string concatenation earlier in the program without issue.
What I would like is to output something like:

"student+[some white space]+letter+[some white space]+className"

Comment: Welcome to one of the symptoms of using "using namespace std". Don't confuse a `C-String` (a simple string-literay, an array of characters, e.g. "hello") with a std::string. When you write `"hello" + "world"` you are actually trying to add two char arrays or two char* pointers. That said, the main problem is *not* the string operator +, it's somewhere else in your code. See http://ideone.com/wKrmu6

Comment: Can you show us how you are using `Grade` objects?

Comment: I'm only in my second term of Com Sci, but if I was going to concatenate strings, I would try using a stringstream. I can't remember exactly, but I think that my instructor said something about how strings in C++ can't be correctly concatenated with just the "+" operator. Check out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/?kw=stringstream for a reference.

Comment: @zsherman Why do you need stringstream? What's wrong with `std::string(const_char_one) + std::string(const_char_two)` or `strcat` if you're using C-style strings? Concating an `std::string` with a `const char*` will Do The Right Thing, but `"hello" + "world"` will not.

Comment: @remyabel like I said, I am a newbie programmer, so this is the first I've heard of either of those options. After googling `strcat` though, I'd agree that it looks much more effective.

Comment: @zsherman You can use a stringstream for formatting but it is not necessary for string concatenation.

Comment: @remyabel: `stringstream` is a more flexible solution as you can easily concatenate string representations of non-string types (`int`, `double`, classes with user-defined streaming operators), using i/o manipulators if desired - if there's a good chance you might want to modify the code to do that later (e.g. adding extra fields to a debug statement) then it's probably best to just start with a `stringstream` so the later code change is quicker and cleaner.

Comment: @TonyD I don't imagine that `std::string("hello" "world") + studentName + std::to_string(someNumber)` is much different from `oss << "hello world" << studentName << someNumber`, but OP is omitting information about why he's getting weird results. I think your answer is enough information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `std::string` can be added to anything (another `std::string`, double-quoted string literal, `char`) and provide intuitive results, ***but*** if you try to add a double-quoted string literal to another string literal or a `char` then it won't "work":

- a string literal added to a `char` or other integral value will undergo Standard Conversion to a `const char*`, then any number added to the pointer will move along the literal that number of characters: if the offset isn't inside the string literal then you get undefined behaviour if you dereference (use) the resultant pointer,
- two string literals just can't be added, even after decaying to two pointers, so you'll get a compile-time error.

Sometimes you will want to explicitly construct a `std::string` so that concatenation with other values works as you'd like: e.g. `my_string = std::string("hello ") + my_const_char_ptr + '\n'`.

Examples:

```
std::string s = "Hello";

s + " World"; // ok
"Hello " + s; // ok
"Hello " + "World"; // NOT ok - two string literals
s += " World"; // ok
s += " Goodbye " + "World"; // NOT ok - "+" evaluated before "+="
s += std::string(" Goodbye ") + "World"; // OK - right-hand-side no longer two literals
                                         // BUT may be slower than two "s +="
```

Comment: Everything you've said is true, but it doesn't explain how `student+"hello"` and `"hello"+student` could act as if `student` were truncated for one of them. For that matter I don't know if there's any rational explanation given the code in the question.

Comment: @MarkRansom: that "truncation" is not possible given the code currently in the question, but I do explain how adding a number to a string literal can give you a pointer somewhere inside the text - that's probably what happened in some earlier version of the code....

Comment: I eventually found out what the problem was. I was getting some information from a file, which had a '\r' character in it. Nonetheless, this answer was the most helpful in tracking down the problem, so I'm marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no operator + for character arrays. So it is obvious that this code

```
string toString() const { string output = "hello"+" world"; return output; }
```

is invalid.

In this expression `"hello"+" world"` there are used two string literals that have the types correspondingly `const char[6]` and `const char[7]`. The operator + is not defined for arrays.

You could just write

```
string toString() const { return string( "hello" ) + " world"; }
```

In this case there is used the operator + overloaded for the class `std::string`. Declaration of the local variable `input` is redundant. So you could simplify the function even the following way

```
string toString() const { return "hello world"; }
```

Comment: This is only a semi-useful answer. Could you expand your answer by possibly explain an alternative way to do what OP is trying to accomplish?

Comment: @zsherman It is a very good answer. No any "alternative ways" are required for valid constructions.

Answer (score 0):

The constant strings `"hello"` and `"world"` are nothing but compile time constants of type `const char*`. Just like you cannot add two `int` pointers:

```
int *p1, *p2;
p1+p1; // Error
```

You cannot add two `(const) char*` objects. This is against the C/C++ language rules. If you must concatenate two const-char-pointers, you can just place them together:

```
"hello"  "world"
```

This technique is mainly useful if you use them along with macros. For example:

```
// Over simplified
#define ONE(_x) _x
#define TWO(_x) _X

ONE("This is") TWO(" concatenation")
```

If you are adding two (or more) runtime C-Strings, you must use `strXXX` functions (like `strcat`), or better use `std::string`.

Comment: For C++ at least, "`"hello"` and `"world"` are nothing but compile time constants of type `const char*`" - actually, their type is `const char[5]` and `const char[6]` respectively, not `const char*`.  There is a Standard Conversion to `const char *` that will be attempted if a match is not found without.

Comment: True that, but when two arrays are added, they get boiled down to pointer-addition notion, not much of difference.

Comment: "when two arrays get added" *never* happens, and if it were made legal and given some semantics by the Standard, there's no particular reason to think the Standard Conversion to pointer would be involved, but I know what you mean... ;-).

Comment: I am not debating here. But VC compiler gives c2110 for `int arr[1]; arr+arr;` ;)